# Status: 500 Internal Server Error Content-type: text/html cron error

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I am using magento 1.9.1.0.. I have scheduled cron jobs for cron.php but i am getting emails as Status:

```
500 Internal Server Error Content-type: text/html cron error ..
```

My cron is not running ,how to fix this issue

Comment: Check your `var/log/exception.log` and `system.log` as well as your server error log and tell us what error is in those files.

Comment: did you recently install patch SUPEE 6788? I know there is some tighter control on cron.php with that patch

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem?